Adding a Column
I am trying to add a column called CATEGORY at the end of the following. My desired input will include the contents of the mutate statement.
Combined States   Institution           Number of Students   Percent of Students     Category

AL                Stillman College       74                   15.78%                  ????

I am having trouble with writing the statement.  Do I need to do another mutate statement?  What I have written is below:
Generate the Top 10 Schools Attended by Students From Each State (States with Top 10 + Students)
Impact_Stats_Main_Top_10_Schools_Summary <- Awards %>%
  select(`Combined_State`, `Institution`, `Student Name`, `Ranking`, `HBCU`, `UNCF_Member`) %>%
  mutate (`Category` = case_when (`Ranking` =='1' | HBCU == TRUE & UNCF_Member == TRUE ~ "1 – UNCF", 
                                  `Ranking` == '2' | HBCU == TRUE  & UNCF_Member == FALSE ~ "2 – HBCU", 
                                  `Ranking` == '3' | HBCU == FALSE  & UNCF_Member == FALSE ~ "3 – Other"                                          
  )) %>%
  group_by (`Combined_State`, `Institution`) %>%
  summarize(`Number of Students` = n_distinct (`Student Name`)) %>%
  mutate(`Percent of Students` = scales::label_percent()(`Number of Students`/sum(`Number of Students`))) %>%
  arrange(Combined_State,desc(`Number of Students`)) %>%
  slice_max(`Number of Students`, n = 10) %>%
  filter(`Number of Students` > 1)     

I tried to add another mutate statement to show the column called CATEGORY.

Its not clear to me what you trying to do. One possible option is to create a limited frame with just the state, institution, and category, then inner join this on the count information that you create in your group_by() and subsequent pipeline

Langtang what I am trying to do is add a column called CATEGORY that will show that institution ranking.   So the line will show the State, Institution, Number of Students, Percentage of students and the Category that I created with the mutate statement that will show the( Category) ranking.

After the Percent of Students column, I want to have the last column called Category to show right after the Percent of Students

The end results will show the State, Institution, Number of Students, Percentage of students and  Category.  Keep in my that I want to keep everything grouped but want to add the Category at the end.  Is it possible to send you a file so you can see what I am looking for?

You may be able to create the Category, and then separate do the counts, and then inner join, like this:

inner_join(
  Awards %>%
    mutate (`Category` = case_when (
    `Ranking` =='1' | HBCU == TRUE & UNCF_Member == TRUE ~ "1 – UNCF",
    `Ranking` == '2' | HBCU == TRUE  & UNCF_Member == FALSE ~ "2 – HBCU",
    `Ranking` == '3' | HBCU == FALSE  & UNCF_Member == FALSE ~ "3 – Other"
  )) %>% 
    select(`Combined_State`, `Institution`,`Category`) %>% 
    distinct(),

  Awards %>% 
    group_by (`Combined_State`, `Institution`) %>%
    summarize(`Number of Students` = n_distinct (`Student Name`),  ) %>%
    mutate(`Percent of Students` = scales::label_percent()(`Number of Students`/sum(`Number of Students`))) %>%
    arrange(Combined_State,desc(`Number of Students`)) %>%
    slice_max(`Number of Students`, n = 10) %>%
    filter(`Number of Students` > 1),

  by = c("Combined_State", "Institution")
)

This may not be the best approach. Your question might benefit from some example data that we could work with.

langtang.  Can I send you the data source?  Maybe that will help you to assist me in what I am trying to accomplish.

langtang...I just had a thought.  Could I not add another statement to show the Category?  For example:  mutate(Catgeory = row_match() (Category) %>%.  Is this the correct way to write the statement or am I missing something?
